# Erro no upload PHP

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou com um desafio que não estou conseguindo entender. Tenho o código abaixo simples de Upload:

```
  list($arquivo, $extensao) = explode(".",$arquivoNome);
  $codificar = md5(date('h:i').$arquivo).".".$extensao;
  $dirArquivo = "uploads/pdf/";
  $upArquivo = $dirArquivo . basename($codificar);
  move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $upArquivo);
```

O arquivo vai corretamente para a pasta, porém quando tento fazer uma verificação:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $upArquivo){
   // Ok...vamos gravar...
}else{
  exit("Erro " .UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE);
}
```

O valor retorna 7, ou seja, falha em gravar o arquivo no disco, mas como se o arquivo foi corretamente para a pasta?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` move o arquivo em questão. Há 2 `move_uploaded_file` no código mesmo? Pode acontecer que a primeira chamada mova corretamente o arquivo e a segunda falhe pois o arquivo da pasta temp já foi movido.

Comment: Exatamente o que o Thomas disse! Completando: para corrigir, basta manter apenas o move_uploaded_file do if, qualquer chamada anterior você deve remover.